# How to separate string into an array in C#?

Tags: c#, arrays, string

I need some help separating a long string from a textbox using ";" into an array of few different strings. I'm programming a simple robot and in this textbox contains the commands for the robots movements, but when fill in few different movements the robot makes only one of them. Here is the code for the box. What can you suggest for my problem?

```
public void ParseCommands(string txtS)
{
    char[] delimiterChars = { ';' };

    string text = txtS;
    System.Console.WriteLine($"Original text: '{text}'");

    string[] words = text.Split(delimiterChars);
    System.Console.WriteLine($"{words.Length} words in text:");
}

private void cmdSend_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        string txtS, lastMsg;
        txtS = txtSend.Text;
        byte[] bySend = Encoding.Default.GetBytes(txtS);
        byte[] byReceive = new byte[255];
        elfinSocket.Send(bySend, 0, txtS.Length, 0);
        int intReceive = elfinSocket.Receive(byReceive, 0, byReceive.Length, 0);
        Array.Resize(ref byReceive, intReceive);
        lastMsg = Encoding.Default.GetString(byReceive);
        lblRecieve.Text = lastMsg;
    }
    catch (SystemException error)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(error.Message);
    }

}
```

Comment: Should `ParseCommands` not _return_ its `words`? Who calls `ParseCommands`?

Comment: What _exactly_ is your problem? It seems (from your `ParseCommands` method) you already know about `string.Split()`, so you know _"how to separate string into array"_. We don't know the protocol - how to talk to your robot. So we can't tell how to send multiple commands.

Comment: The problem is that the robot does not execute all of the movements that are set and just executes only one of them e.g. left;right;up;left -> moves just to the left. The protocol I'm using is TCP/IP. I need to make it recognize them as different commands.

Comment: then you need to use your `ParseCommand` method. What did you write it for? ;) and send each command separately

Comment: did any of the answers helped you to solve your problem?

Answer (score 1):

it seems that you should also use the tool that you have implemented. Deconstruct the command string into parts and send all parts in a loop. You should return the array in the `ParseCommands` method:

```
public string[]ParseCommands(string txtS)
{
    char[] delimiterChars = { ';' };

    string text = txtS;
    System.Console.WriteLine($"Original text: '{text}'");

    string[] words = text.Split(delimiterChars);
    System.Console.WriteLine($"{words.Length} words in text:");
    return words;
}

private void cmdSend_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string txtS, lastMsg;
    txtS = txtSend.Text;

    string[] commands = ParseCommands(txtS);     

    foreach (var element in commands)
    {       
        byte[] bySend = Encoding.Default.GetBytes(element);
        byte[] byReceive = new byte[255];
        elfinSocket.Send(bySend, 0, txtS.Length, 0);
        int intReceive = elfinSocket.Receive(byReceive, 0, byReceive.Length, 0);
        Array.Resize(ref byReceive, intReceive);
        lastMsg = Encoding.Default.GetString(byReceive);
        lblRecieve.Text = lastMsg;
    }
}
```

Disclaimer: It seems that it will be a longer lasting procedure, so you won't see the updates of the received response messages in your label:

```
lblRecieve.Text = lastMsg;
```

You would need to make it async and put this code into a separate method. Then await each time the response and write it into the label.

The async version could look like this:

```
private async void cmdSend_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string txtS, lastMsg;
    txtS = txtSend.Text;

    string[] commands = ParseCommands(txtS);     

    foreach (var element in commands)
    {   
        string response = await Task.Run(()=>
        {   
            byte[] bySend = Encoding.Default.GetBytes(element);
            byte[] byReceive = new byte[255];
            elfinSocket.Send(bySend, 0, txtS.Length, 0);
            int intReceive = elfinSocket.Receive(byReceive, 0, byReceive.Length, 0);
            Array.Resize(ref byReceive, intReceive);
            return Encoding.Default.GetString(byReceive);
        });
        lblRecieve.Text = response;
    }
}
```

This should avoid the freezing of the GUI

Comment: Shouldn't it be commands instead of sequence in the foreach loop?

Comment: @Auneell thank you, copy paste mistake, I was too lazy to write the foreach, so I generated it by a snippet in LINQPad ;) corrected it

Answer (score -1):

```
Try This

public void ParseCommands(string txtS)
    {
        // String  
        string text = txtS;  
        // String separator  
        string[] delimiterChars = new string[] { ":" };  
        // String Split
        string[] words = text.Split(delimiterChars , StringSplitOptions.None ); 

        foreach (string firstName in words)  
        Console.WriteLine(firstName);
    }
```